# Addition and Multiplication in Graphs of Functions VS Probability Distributions

Tags: probability, geometry, probability-distributions, graphing-functions

Why is it the case that adding a constant to a function shifts its graph vertically, but adding a constant to a probability distribution shifts its graph horizontally?

Similarly, why is it the case that multiplying a function by a constant stretches its graph vertically, but multiplying a probability distribution by a constant stretches its graph horizontally?

I understand that shifting or stretching a probability distribution vertically would violate the condition that the area under its graph must be $1$ (PMF/PDF) or that its graph must approach $1$ (CDF), but I'm curious as to what difference in the geometric setup accounts for this differing behavior.

Comment: Are you talking about the difference between $f(x)+a$ and $f(x+a)$?  These aren't the same thing at all.

Comment: @saulspatz Not exactly, it would be the difference between $y = f(x)$ -> $y = f(x) + a$ (where $x$ and $y$ are high school algebra variables) and $Y = g(X)$ -> $Y = g(X) + a$ (where $X$ and $Y$ are random variables), and similarly for a multiplicative constant $b$ in place of the additive constant $a$.

Comment: There is no difference between those.  Random variables are just a particular kind of function.  Can you give a concrete example of what it is that's bothering you?

Comment: Wait.  Are you talking about the difference between $F(x)=\Pr(G(X)<x)$ and $H(x)=\Pr(G(X)+a<x)$?  In that case, $H(x)=F(x-a)$

Comment: @saulspatz This might be what I'm after.  For example, Wikipedia states, "If $Z$ is a standard normal deviate, then $X = \sigma Z + \mu$ will have a normal distribution with expected value $\mu$  and standard deviation $\sigma$," which corresponds to stretching and shifting the distribution.

Comment: Yes, then it's just like any other function.  Remember that you are graphing the distribution, not the random variable.